# Android - error on app startup when testing on my own device

Tags: android

I have a free Android app out there and I am trying to create a paid version. I am trying to test it on my device, and I keep getting this crash log when I first open the app on my phone:

```
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    The import android.app cannot be resolved
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    Application cannot be resolved to a type
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    Override cannot be resolved to a type
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    The type android.app.Application cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    The method init(Application) from the type ACRA refers to the missing type Application
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    Application cannot be resolved to a type
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    at business.premium.MyApplication.<init>(MyApplication.java:3)
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
10-25 12:33:26.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18061):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:966)
```

Would anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks!!

EDIT:

Here is my whole MyApplication.java

```
package business.premium;

import android.app.Application;

import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "my_key")
public class MyApplication extends Application
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
        super.onCreate();    

    }   
}
```

Comment: Show us your `MyApplication.java` code please, first 20 lines or so is probably sufficient.

Comment: @Ralgha Just added it to the original question :)

Comment: Did this class every fully compile in Eclipse? Or is Eclipse showing red warning signs on the file and class icon?

Comment: @Codo eclipse seems to suggest it is ok.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new project, just the basic new Android app from Project|New in Eclipse, and add the same MyApplication class to it (and the necessary libraries and manifest entries, of course), and see what happens.

Comment: the examples I've seen, have super.onCreate() first, then the ACRA.init(this);... I'd flip them and see if that helps some

Comment: Also you're missing formURI
`@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", /* This is required for backward compatibility but not used */ formUri = "http://www.backendofyourchoice.com/reportpath")`